# Do you get credit towards your tag score after hitting your daily reputation limit?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, tag-score

I forget what the exact value is (200?) but after you hit your daily reputation limit, you will not earn any more reputation for additional upvotes.

My question is do you still get points towards tags for up-votes after that point? Are the two coupled?

For example, say I answer a question about [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). At that time my [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag had 800 points. If I'm at my 200 reputation limit, but then receive 5 upvotes, does my [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag score increment to 805? Or does it freeze too when my reputation limit is hit?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Tag score isn't impacted by reputation limit.  While you stop gaining reputation for upvotes past 200, you will still be gaining scores in your given tag.

Comment: This can also result in you earning tag badges for .. interesting things, which is precisely why I have one for C++ :) Folks tag .. interestingly, sometimes.