# How do top tag user points behave when you hit the daily reputation limit?

Tags: support, tags, daily-reputation-limit

Do upvotes count for "top users" points for a specific tag even when you hit the limit of 200 reputation per day? I could not find any information about that. I found only that the upvotes will count for *badges*, in [Do you get credit towards your tag score after hitting your daily reputation limit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296187)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you do. The daily limit only concerns *reputation*, and the *tag score* is based on a slightly different criterium: it's just the total score of your (non-wiki) answers on questions with that tag. This is true for both the 'badges' and the 'top users per tag'.